# How to get minimum, maximum, and available products for a product

Tags: magento-1.9, cataloginventory

I need to find the stock details of a product how to find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('productid');
$stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                ->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
  if($stocklevel>0){
        $inStock='1';
    }else{
        $inStock='2';
    }
    $availableQty=$stocklevel;
    $_stock_data = $product->getStockItem()->getData();
    $_qtde_max = (intval($_stock_data['max_sale_qty'])) ? intval($_stock_data['max_sale_qty']) : 10000;
    $_qtde_min=(intval($_stock_data['min_sale_qty'])) ? intval($_stock_data['min_sale_qty']) : 1;
    $maxQty=$_qtde_max;
    $minQty=$_qtde_min;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($products as $_product){

$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);

echo $stock->getQty();
echo $stock->getMinQty();
echo $stock->getMinSaleQty();

}
```